# Mismatched namespaces in xmlns and schemaLocation attributes in XML document

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I've found an example in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_howto.asp), that shows, how to refer to an XML Schema.

For the following XSD (`note.xsd`)...:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

...XML instance is proposed:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<note
xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com/xml note.xsd">
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Notice, that `xmlns` and `xsi:schemaLocation` in XML document *have different namespaces URIs*. I know, that URIs aren't parsed and trigger no network activity, but is it correct to define different URIs in this case (*even if domain names are the same*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it isn't correct. Those namespaces should match, otherwise validator won't bind namespace of XML document (in this case - default namespace, `https://www.w3schools.com`) with appropriate elements declarations / type definitions in schema from `note.xsd`.

Let's valid given XML against schema above:

[image: XML validation failed]

And now validate XML document with *matched* namespaces:

[image: XML validation is successful]

In my opinion, it's just a typo, because the same XML snippet (but with matched namespaces) is represented in the [next section](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_schema.asp).